# jQuery plug-in data access -- performance hit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-data

I'm writing a new jQuery plugin. For the guide, I am using their recommendation:

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { 
      return this.each(function(){

        var $this = $(this),
          data = $this.data('tooltip'),
          tooltip = $('<div />', {
            text : $this.attr('title')
          });

          // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
          if ( ! data ) {
            data = {
               element : this,
               target : $this,
               tooltip : tooltip
            };
            $(this).data('tooltip', data);

          }
        methods.update.apply(data.element, 'Test');
    },
    update : function( content ) { 
      var $this = $(this),
         data = $this.data('tooltip');

        // check or change something important in the data.

        private.test.apply( data.element );

        return data.element;
    }
  };

  var private = {
      test: function() {
          var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data('tooltip');

          // again, do some operation with data
      }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

Its a little different from their version to make it shorter but also to show my differences. Basically, in the init, I am instantiating and creating data object that gets stored in the element. Part of the data object is the element itself:

```
element : this,
```

Then, after all of the initialization is done, I call a public method from the init (lets say I do it for functionality reuse purpose). To make the call, I use .apply() and provide the proper context (my element), which would match the context when the function is called externally:

```
return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
```

This is fine and understandable. However, what I am unsure about is the performance of acquiring the data of the plugin from within a private or a public method. To me, it seems that at the top of every public and private method I have to execute the following lines in order to get the data:

```
var $this = $(this),
     data = $this.data('tooltip');
```

Of course, I wouldn't execute them when I have no need for whatever is stored in data. However, my plugin performs quite a bit of animations and state tracking and almost all of the functions require access to the data. As such, it seems like accessing .data() in almost every private and public call is a pretty big performance hit.

My question is whether anyone uses this plug-in structure (I'm hoping that yes since jQuery recommends it) and has found a different way of referencing the data without hitting .data() in every function call.

Comment: have you noticed a performance hit? something slowing down? `.data()` doesn't actually access the DOM after the first time, so it's generally pretty quick.

Comment: I will not say I have until I run some tests to prove to myself but that was my impression that it has. Does it fetch it from some cache (hash or something)? Thanks for the comment. If it doesn't access DOM, its great news :D !

Comment: From the docs: 'The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).' http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Hmm, but I also found this: "Calling .data() with no parameters retrieves all of the values as a JavaScript object. This object can be safely cached in a variable as long as a new object is not set with .data(obj). Using the object directly to get or set values is faster than making individual calls to .data() to get or set each value:" I wonder if I can return methods[ method ].apply( $(this).data('tooltip'), Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));